# Distributed Config File For Sharding - Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I use this config:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true, (Also I have tried false value)
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": "majority",
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "newNodeStrategy": "static",
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "class_01": {
      "servers": ["n01"]
    },
    "class_02": {
      "servers": ["n01","n02"]
    },
    "class_03": {
      "servers": ["n03"]
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone use something like this config and could use this query: `Select from Class` (not `Select from class_01 or Select from class_02 ...`)
As I read "[Read records](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Distributed-Sharding.html#read-records)", it is possible to use `Select from Class`. But I can't use it.
Even if I run `Select from cluster:class_03` from n01 I won't have response (I will get error)
If I run `Select from cluster:class_01` from n01 I will get the result.

What should I do?
(FYI: My orientdb version is 2.2.33)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This is an error that I get:
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: No active nodes found to execute command: sql.select rid from index:User.idNumber where key = ?

Comment: And I get this warning in my Orientdb console:
WARNI I/O Error on distributed channel (clientId=8 reqType=121 error=java.io.InvalidClassException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OBasicResultSet; no valid constructor)

Comment: I don't have errors with the Orientdb version 2.0.7!

Answer (score 0):

with 2.2.33 and 2.2.30 I have no problem, have you tried to run a CHECK DATABASE?

Comment: I haven't tried. When I shutdown the Orientdb servers I couldn't start them again (NOT_AVAILABLE situation). I think maybe it is because of my configuration. Would you please share the config file(default-distributed-db-config.json)?

Comment: Version 2.2.30 is almost OK.

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your config file, there is no "class_03" in it.

```
    "class_02": {
      "servers": ["n01","n02"]
    },
    "class_02": {
      "servers": ["n03"]
    },
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo when I wanted to simplify my problem. My problem solved with version 2.2.30. But It still exist with version 2.2.33.